# SVN Merge Between Sibling Branches

Tags: svn, merge

In SVN I have two branches, 1.0 and 2.0.  If I fix an issue in 1.0, how do I merge that fix into 2.0 and vice versa?

Consider the following scenario:

1. I make a fix on the 1.0 branch and it creates a new file A (rev X).
2. I do a plain merge with just that fix from 1.0 to 2.0 (rev X+1)
3. I then make a fix on the 2.0 branch and it modifies A (rev Y).
4. If I merge that fix back to 1.0 I get a merge conflict!

I suppose I can always force that fixes are made on the 1.0 branch first or I could manually block the X+1 revision on the 1.0 branch.  Both of these are non-ideal and I was wondering if there were a better way to handle sibling branches.

Comment: We do not do it often, but whenever it happens we go with manual block (i.e. `--record-only`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'best' way is going to depend on the purpose of your branches.

For example, if branch 1.0 is for bug fixes and branch 2.0 is for testing then it makes sense to do all fixes on 1.0 first, then push to 2.0.

If they're different projects and you want to cherrypick which features get merged between branches then you could use the trunk as the centralised point.

If both branches are going to have the same files and changes and neither is authoritative it begs the question do you really need both?

Ultimately, you're going to have conflicts if both branches involve making changes on the same files, it's just down to your circumstances as to which is less hassle to deal with day to day.

Comment: The branches are different releases of the same product.  We have to continue to support customers still on 1.0 and release patches while at the same time do new development on 2.0.  Engineers maintaining the 1.0 branch will often discover bugs and fix them and those same bugs apply on the 2.0 branch.  Engineers developing the new 2.0 branch discover bugs that also could affect the 1.0 release and want to push those changes back as well.

Comment: After more discussion I believe using the trunk as a centralized point is the ideal scenario.